# Get array count of specific document in Pymongo

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, pymongo

I've looked around a lot but I couldn't manage to find an answer. It's probably easy but I just can't manage to do this.

I have a collection with some documents and in these documents there are multiple arrays.

I want to know how to query for a document and then do a count for a specific array in that document.
Something like the following:

```
    db.test.find_one({"id":"test"}).count("specific_array")
```

The result should only return the amount of documents inside the specified array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide sample documents with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I couldn't find anything useful which does what I want I decided to just use Python for it.
To return just the array I used:

```
result = db.test.find_one({"id":"test"},{'_id':0, 'specific_array':1})
```

then I converted it too a string:

```
strresult = str(result)
```

After that I needed to know the length so if the length was > 16 I gave a command.

```
if len(strresult) > 16:
    dosomething
```

This isn't optimal, but it does work, if someone finds a better way I will delete this answer and select the better answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread:

[mongodb count sub-document and list totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713473/mongodb-count-sub-document-and-list-totals)

It is the only way to perform what you want...

However you probably can overide the cursor method to accept your subdocument and only return the array size, but i don't recommend you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `aggregate` with `match` and `project`

```
db.test.aggregate([{$match : {id: "test"}},{$project: {count : {$size : "$specific_array"}, specific_array: "$specfic_array"}}])
```

It will return multiple documents matching the filter `{id: "test"}`. Resulted documents will only include the fields specified inside `$project`.