# Counting documents that match subarray conditions in MongoDB

Tags: laravel, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a database with many documents structured similar to:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("586c0f07d0ad7a2b8b08c572"),
   "auto_vehicles" : [ 
       {
           "year" : "2017",
           "make" : "SUBARU",
       },
       {
           "year" : "2011",
           "make" : "CHEVROLET",            
       }
   ],
   "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-03T20:52:23.192Z")
}
```

Assuming I wanted to get a count of all documents that had a 'auto_vehicles.make' that was equal to 'SUBARU' I have tried to do the following:

collection.find({'auto_vehicles.make':'SUBARU'}).count();

But the returned value doesn't appear to be correct (substantially under-representing the actual database population).

I suspect that perhaps find does not search within sub-arrays like this?

Additional information:  I am performing these queries via Laravel 5.2 w/ Jenssegers MongoDB Eloquent model and Query builder (Moloquent) from https://jenssegers.com/

Your thoughts are greatly appreciated - thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb count sub-document and list totals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713473/mongodb-count-sub-document-and-list-totals)

Comment: Thank you @RyanWheale - I do not see how that item relates - perhaps I'm missing the overlap / you could explain further?  Thank you

Comment: Ah, I misread your question on first reading. Either way, you will need to use aggregation when querying subdocuments like this. Checkout `$match`, `$unwind`, and `$group`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. You've to make use of aggregation for this one as you need the count across all documents.

$match to keep only embedded arrays that has matching make.

$unwind the embedded arrays

$match to keep only the matching make.

$group to sum the matching make.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "auto_vehicles.make": 'SUBARU'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$auto_vehicles"
},
{
    $match: {
        "auto_vehicles.make": 'SUBARU'
    }
},{
    $group: {
        _id: "$auto_vehicles.make",
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}]);
```

Update:

$filter to embedded docs on the matching criteria.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "auto_vehicles": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$auto_vehicles",
                "as": "result",
                "cond": {
                    "$eq": ["$$result.make", 'SUBARU']
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$auto_vehicles"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$auto_vehicles.make",
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: This works although I believe there is a superfluous second $match - I need to run an experiment to be certain though.

Many thanks for your time and effort!